# Skip certain number in mysql auto-increment

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I've currently made a simple record table, with the recordID as the auto-increment primary key, the question is, due to religious reasons, my employer **DOES NOT** want to include the number 4 and 6 in the recordID, so instead of checking the recordID everytime after the record has been made, is there a much easier way to solve my current problem?

**EDIT:**

Here's a quick test table I've created based on Vanojx1's answer. So what did I do wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` int(11) NOT NULL
)

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `jump4and6` BEFORE INSERT ON `test` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET @nextId = (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `test`);
    IF (@nextId IN (4,6)) THEN
        SET NEW.id = @nextId + 1;
        SET @nextId = @nextId + 2;
    ELSE
        SET NEW.id = @nextId;
        SET @nextId = @nextId + 1;
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO `test`(`id`) VALUES (@nextId);
    END
$$
DELIMITER ;

ALTER TABLE `test` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);
ALTER TABLE `test` MODIFY `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Everything works so far, but when I tried to insert a row:

```
INSERT INTO `test`(value) VALUES (123456);
```

This happens.

```
#1442 - Can't update table 'test' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

Comment: auto-increment will always increment the recordID on creation of eachrow. so you can insert and delete that rows alter but you cannot skip the auto-increament on/or before creation

Comment: This is interesting actually. I am not aware of any such function and would love to follow this thread. The only thig i can think of is checking the ID of the last inserted row, and if the next is 4 ||6 then simply insert a FOO row and instantly delete it to save DB space. For informational reasons, I'd also want to know what religion is being addressed here and the relation to these numbers if you do not mind.

Comment: @RuslanAbuzant I'm coding for medical record, the number 4 in Chinese has a similar sound with "Death" (hence medical buildings often will skip floor number 4), as for 6, it's more christian, due to the reference of 666 for being satan.

Comment: If an id has any meaning beyond the internal scope of the database, then do not use an auto_increment for this. Despite it's name, the auto_increment feature has but one purpose; to ensure that values comprising the PRIMARY KEY are unique and sequential. Whether or not they are consecutive is irrelevant.

Comment: @Strawberry so is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: I think so. I think you're confusing data storage and retrieval with data display. All that really needs to happen is that some kind of clever unique hash of the numbers is constructed which somehow excludes the numbers 4 and 6.

Answer (score -2):

You can create the primary key as an integer, then use a trigger before insert like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER jump4and6 
BEFORE INSERT 
ON your_table
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET @nextId = (SELECT MAX(current_index) FROM your_table_sequence);
    IF (@nextId IN (4,6)) THEN
        SET NEW.id = @nextId + 1;
        SET @nextId = @nextId + 2;
    ELSE
        SET NEW.id = @nextId;
        SET @nextId = @nextId + 1;
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO your_table_sequence (current_index) VALUES (@nextId);
END$$
```

You also need a table to store your primary key sequence

Comment: Hm, this does seem to work, but what if, let's say, current ID = 39, the next ID would become 40, but according to the script, it'll just make it 41, which still fails due to there's 4 in the ID =/

Comment: No, 'everything different from 4 and 6' IN (4,6) will return false. id needs to be an integer

Comment: Alright, I've tried your method, but something went wrong. Please check the post again, and help me identify where went wrong? Thanks

Comment: I ve tested this and seems to work fine on my test db.... remove auto increment from column id of test table.